mongodb deleteManyAsync() makes the performance slower
 public async Task RemoveAllNotificationsAsync(){
    await databaseContext.Notification.DeleteManyAsync(Builders<Db.Notification>.Filter.Empty);
auditLogger.LogInformation(Codes.Data_Notification_AllCleared, "Allnotifications are cleared.");  }

I am using mongodb deleteManyAsync() method to delete all notifications in one go, but for large data sets it takes time to delete. why? Is there any technique to improve the performance. for example i am generating 1000000 notifications while i am deleting this bulk it takes 5 mins to delete
